# Update operation failed with SQLCODE=-803, how to troubleshoot?

Tags: sql, db2, sql-update

I am trying to update table records based on some condition. When I update few number of recent records it works fine but when I run it for more number records or older records it throws errors 
Query :

```
update table_Name set Col1 = 'C' 
where date(TRN_SCH_DPT_DT)  < current date - 200 DAYS
```

Works fine!

```
update table_Name set Col1 = 'C'
where date(TRN_SCH_DPT_DT)  < current date - 100 DAYS
```

Throws error => DB2 SQL Error:

> SQLCODE=-803, SQLSTATE=23505, SQLERRMC=2

Note: I am not updating primary key. Any number greater than 200 is working fine.

Comment: Find which unique-constraint you are breaking, and fix it.  Better to use MERGE for cases like this.

Comment: Side note: Your current query is possibly ignoring any index you may have on `TRN_SCH_DPT_DT`.  It would be better for you to write the condition as `WHERE TRN_SCH_DPT_DT < TIMESTAMP(CURRENT DATE - 100 DAYS)`

Answer (score 2):

There is a SELECT statement in the description of [SQL0803N](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc-gentopic2.html#sql0803n), which can help you find an unique index (with IID=2) your statement tries to violate.

> SELECT INDNAME, INDSCHEMA
>   FROM SYSCAT.INDEXES
>   WHERE IID = 2
>   AND TABSCHEMA = '*TABLE_SCHEMA*' AND TABNAME = '*TABLE_NAME*'

Comment: You might want to include salient points from the link in your answer, lest the link goes stale.